# GetDescendantsByTemplateWithFallback in Sitecore 10.1

Tags: content-search, upgrade

We are upgrading from Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 10.1.

The method `GetDescendantsByTemplateWithFallback` exist in Sitecore.ConentSearch.dll Version 2 but this method is missing in Sitecore.ConentSearch.dll Version 8.

```
 property.GetDescendantsByTemplateWithFallback(Templates.PropertyPageTemplateID);
```

Is there any alternative to `GetDescendantsByTemplateWithFallback` that can be used in Sitecore 10.1?

Comment: Does this help you? https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0097529

Comment: @Gaurav agarwal. Thanks for the link but this is something different because the link talks about resolving the error. In my case i am looking for alternative to GetDescendantsByTemplateWithFallback method in Sitecore 10.1 because this method doesn’t exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LanguageFallbackDataService` was marked as obsolete in **9.3**.

No replacement was provided in obsolete info.

This [kb](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0097529) article describes a bug which is strictly related to `GetDescendantsByTemplateWithFallback` extension method

### Replacement

I tracked how previous usages in Sitecore were updated and I found one. Here is  a code example:

**before**

```c#
result = property.GetDescendantsByTemplateWithFallback(Templates.PropertyPageTemplateID)
```

**after**

```c#
var templateID = new TemplateID(ID.Parse(Templates.PropertyPageTemplateID));
result = property.Axes.GetDescendants().Where(i => i.TemplateID == templateID)
```

You can create your own extension method and put this implementation there.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The following extension method would be equivalent to a deprecated search utility.

```
public static IEnumerable<Item> GetDescendantsByTemplateWithFallback(this Item rootItem, string templateID) {
  var items = new List<Item>();
  ID templateId = new ID(templateID);
  var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(new SitecoreIndexableItem(rootItem));
  using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext()) {
    items = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
                .Where(x => x.TemplateId == templateId &&
                            x.Path.StartsWith(rootItem.Paths.FullPath))
                .Select(i => i.GetItem())
                .ToList();
  }
  return items;
}
```